# slam_toolbox windows 10

Tags: windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I installed ROS_foxy on windows10, and trying to get the package slam_toolbox to work
What I tried was first to check if there is any existing package inside of choco, using this command:

```
choco install ros-foxy-slam-toolbox
```

This told me no packages were available, so I tried this as they said to get the source and build it into the workspace:

```
git clone -b foxy-devel git@github.com:stevemacenski/slam_toolbox.git
```

I then did colcon build in order to build it, but without any succes, getting multiple errors in the karto_sdk.

Here is the console output while using verbose mode:

```
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk\Karto.h(2798,37): warning C4101: 'ex': unreferenced local variable [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(266,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::RegisterSensor': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1574,8): message : see previous definition of 'RegisterSensor' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(282,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::GetScan': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1582,24): message : see previous definition of 'GetScan' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(314,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::SetLastScan': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1610,8): message : see previous definition of 'SetLastScan' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(323,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::ClearLastScan': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1616,8): message : see previous definition of 'ClearLastScan' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(332,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::ClearLastScan': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1622,8): message : see previous definition of 'ClearLastScan' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(341,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::AddScan': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1645,8): message : see previous definition of 'AddScan' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(361,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::RemoveScan': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1657,8): message : see previous definition of 'RemoveScan' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(394,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::ClearRunningScans': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1676,8): message : see previous definition of 'ClearRunningScans' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(404,1): warning C4273: 'karto::MapperSensorManager::SetRunningScanBufferSize': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Mapper.h(1687,8): message : see previous definition of 'SetRunningScanBufferSize' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,8): error C2065: 'uint': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'i' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,15): error C2059: syntax error: '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,20): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,39): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(408,42): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(409,26): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(409,72): error C2059: syntax error: ';' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(413,6): error C2653: 'MapperSensorManager': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(415,3): error C2065: 'm_RunningBufferMaximumDistance': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(417,15): error C2065: 'Name': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(417,8): error C2923: 'std::vector': 'Name' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(417): message : see declaration of 'Name' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(417,8): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\include\boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp(135): message : see declaration of 'std::vector' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(417,29): error C3861: 'GetSensorNames': identifier not found [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(417,45): error C2514: 'std::vector': class template cannot be constructed [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
C:\opt\ros\foxy\x64\include\boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp(135): message : see declaration of 'std::vector' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,8): error C2065: 'uint': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,13): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'i' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,15): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,15): error C2059: syntax error: '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,20): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,36): error C2662: 'allocator_traits<allocator_traits<_Alloc>::rebind_alloc<_Ty>>::size_type std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::size(void) noexcept const': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'std::vector' to 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,36): message : Reason: cannot convert from 'std::vector' to 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,25): message : Conversion requires a second user-defined-conversion operator or constructor [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\vector(1547,49): message : see declaration of 'std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::size' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,39): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(418,42): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(419,26): error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(419,5): error C3861: 'GetScanManager': identifier not found [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(419,90): error C2059: syntax error: ';' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(421,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(421,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(427,26): error C2653: 'MapperSensorManager': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(428,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(428,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(447,6): error C2653: 'MapperSensorManager': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2653: 'ScanManagerMap': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2065: 'iterator': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'iter' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2059: syntax error: '=' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2065: 'iter': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2065: 'm_ScanManagers': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(451,3): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(453,12): error C2065: 'iter': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(453,24): error C2059: syntax error: ';' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(454,5): error C2065: 'iter': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(457,17): error C3927: '->': trailing return type is not allowed after a non-function declarator [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(457,17): error C3484: syntax error: expected '->' before the return type [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(457,18): error C3613: missing return type after '->' ('int' assumed) [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(457,23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(457,18): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'clear' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(458,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(458,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(464,1): error C2653: 'ScanMatcher': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(464,15): error C2523: '<Unknown>::~ScanMatcher': destructor tag mismatch [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(465,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(465,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(477,13): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(477,13): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(477,15): error C2825: 'ScanMatcher': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(477,28): error C2510: 'ScanMatcher': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(478,3): error C2065: 'Mapper': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(478,12): error C2065: 'pMapper': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(478,21): error C2275: 'kt_double': illegal use of this type as an expression [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Types.h(67): message : see declaration of 'kt_double' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(478,31): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'searchSize' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(480,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(480,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(535,11): error C2825: 'ScanMatcher': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(535,24): error C2510: 'ScanMatcher': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(536,3): error C2065: 'LocalizedRangeScan': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(536,24): error C2065: 'pScan': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(536,31): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(536,31): error C2059: syntax error: 'const' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(538,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(538,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(641,6): error C2825: 'ScanMatcher': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(641,19): error C2510: 'ScanMatcher': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(642,1): error C2270: '()': modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(645,32): error C2065: 'm_yPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(645,50): error C2065: 'm_yPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(645,71): error C2065: 'm_yPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(647,28): error C2065: 'm_xPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(649,28): error C2065: 'm_rSearchCenter': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(650,23): error C2653: 'math': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(650,29): error C3861: 'Square': identifier not found [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(652,55): error C2065: 'm_xPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(652,82): error C2065: 'm_xPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(655,5): error C2065: 'x_pose': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(655,28): error C2065: 'm_xPoses': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(657,30): error C2065: 'm_rSearchCenter': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(658,25): error C2653: 'math': is not a class or namespace name [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(658,31): error C3861: 'Square': identifier not found [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(660,5): error C2065: 'Vector2': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(660,13): error C2275: 'kt_int32s': illegal use of this type as an expression [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Types.h(35): message : see declaration of 'kt_int32s' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(660,24): error C2065: 'gridPoint': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(661,7): error C2065: 'm_pCorrelationGrid': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(661,39): error C2065: 'Vector2': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(661,47): error C2275: 'kt_double': illegal use of this type as an expression [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\include\karto_sdk/Types.h(67): message : see declaration of 'kt_double' [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(662,27): error C2065: 'm_pCorrelationGrid': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(662,57): error C2065: 'gridPoint': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(666,28): error C2065: 'm_rSearchCenter': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(666,59): error C2065: 'm_searchAngleOffset': undeclared identifier [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
D:\ros2_ws\src\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\src\Mapper.cpp(666,78): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation [D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\lib\karto_sdk\kartoSlamToolbox.vcxproj]
  Building Custom Rule D:/ros2_ws/src/slam_toolbox/CMakeLists.txt
  slam_toolbox__python.vcxproj -> D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\rosidl_generator_py\slam_toolbox\slam_toolbox__python.dll
  Building Custom Rule D:/ros2_ws/src/slam_toolbox/CMakeLists.txt
  slam_toolbox__rosidl_typesupport_c__pyext.vcxproj -> D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\rosidl_generator_py\slam_toolbox\slam_toolbox_s__rosidl_typesupport_c.pyd
  Building Custom Rule D:/ros2_ws/src/slam_toolbox/CMakeLists.txt
  slam_toolbox__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c__pyext.vcxproj -> D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\rosidl_generator_py\slam_toolbox\slam_toolbox_s__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.pyd
  Building Custom Rule D:/ros2_ws/src/slam_toolbox/CMakeLists.txt
  slam_toolbox__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c__pyext.vcxproj -> D:\ros2_ws\build\slam_toolbox\rosidl_generator_py\slam_toolbox\slam_toolbox_s__rosidl_typesupport_introspection_c.pyd
Failed   <<< slam_toolbox [39.4s, exited with code 1]
```

Sorry for the really long log
Any idea of what can be causing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391068/slam_toolbox-windows-10/) by [ioness](https://answers.ros.org/users/89817/ioness/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So after quite sometimes looking around, found the solution, which was to use this github, which contains a fix for windows about this precise error:
https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox/pull/440
I can keep working now on getting my setup working for ros2/Unity

---

Originally posted by [ioness](https://answers.ros.org/users/89817/ioness/) with karma: 11 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-17**:
Glad you found the answer. Thank you for sharing. You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.